# Vuetify - DatePicker to select two dates only

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I am having v-date-picker with multiple property. Is it possible to restrict the datepicker to select 2 dates only. Please help me out.

[image: Working Picker]

[image: CustomDateWithIssue]

[image: DatePickerIssue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hack could be using `range` instead of `multiple` because at the end the `dates array` will have only two dates when using `range`.

Comment: When i tried Range, the date is selected based on user intrest. If user clickon date 05-08-2020 at first and then click on date 01-08-2020, the text will be shown as 05-08-2020 ~ 01-08-2020. How can i make 01-08-2020 to come at first .

Comment: try sorting dates before joining them in the computed property

Answer (score 0):

you can use `range` and then add rules to your `v-date-picker` template (example `v-text-field`). so it will return error if the user input is not suitable. try this rules:

`visitDate: [v => this.date[0] <= this.date[1] || "Finish Date can't be earlier than Start Date"]`.

src: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/

Comment: I should give this on v-date-picker?

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#date-pickers-range check out this documentation. on `v-text-field` you can apply the rules.

Comment: you can wrap your `v-date-picker` on `v-menu`. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#date-pickers-in-dialog-and-menu like on this documentation. since `v-date-picker` doesn't have rules props you need to wrap it using `v-text-field`.

Comment: So i have to set this as a rule.Right

Comment: correct. set the rules on `v-text-field` or if you prefer not using `v-text-field`, you can use computed property on your range date and return false if the input doesn't meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Using `range` works in this scenario. In addition, I would like to mention the approach that I used to arrange the date in the right order.For example, Clicking on the date 2020-03-29 then clicking on 2020-03-23 will show 2020-03-29 ~ 2020-03-23.

```
<v-menu
    ref="menu"
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :return-value.sync="dates"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    min-width="auto"
>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="dateRangeText"
            label="Picker in menu"
            prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
            readonly
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
        ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
        v-model="dates"
        range
        no-title
        scrollable
        :min="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
    >           
    </v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

The simplest way that I found so far is to write a condition to check for the `v-text-field`

```
computed: {
    dateRangeText () {
        if (Date.parse(this.dates[1]) < Date.parse(this.dates[0])) {
                let temp = this.dates[1]
                this.dates[1] = this.dates[0]
                this.dates[0] = temp
        }
        return this.dates.join(' ~ ')
    },
},
```